# How can i display NEXRAD data in 3d on matplotlib

Tags: meteorology, python

How do i get nexrad data from KHGX (Houston)  in 3D to display in matplotlib

Comment: Going to have explain what you mean by 3-D... if you mean cross sections, metpy may well be a fair option (only played with it a bit).  If you mean from any viewing angle with matching maps, I'm not sure the tools are out there in python yet, though I'd be quite interested if we find out that's wrong!

Comment: But from my memory of playing around with it last year, it'll take a little work at least to setup scripts to acquire and view the data, it's not just a couple lines of code or such.  The python libraries are nowhere close to a replacement for software like GRLevel2, unless things have evolved than I've thought :)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Im trying to convert the Nexrad data into volumetric data like what Gr2Analyist

Comment: I thought I remembered seeing cross-sections at least with metpy, but doesn't look like it.  You could probably develop it with some work, but it still wouldn't have the quality of GR.  Unfortunately a lot of top quality time went into GR that so far hasn't been replicated at open source level to my knowledge, as is the case in many fields.  Just not worth it for people to develop it.

Comment: Ah, looks like I found the tool, it's part of pyart, not metpy... https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart-docs-travis/API/generated/pyart.util.cross_section_rhi.html  No example image, but it'd just be a cross section, not truly 3-D.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097364/how-to-plot-3d-gridded-weather-radar-data-in-python also asks the same.  The linked https://www.vapor.ucar.edu does seem to offer some feasibility, but definitely looks like there's still nothing that can do it easy.